# PHP mkdir() and move_uploaded_file() Permission Denied with 777

Tags: php, iis, file-upload, mkdir, 777

I am writing a PHP script for a client which will be installed on a server which I do not have back-end access to. I only have access to a particular folder and database.

My script will upload files and create folders. However I get a permission denied error when I try run `mkdir()` and `move_uploaded_file()`. Here are the conditions:

- Server running IIS 6 and PHP 5.1.2 (a bad, ancient mixture, I know)
- Folder where I try to  make a directory and upload a file has 777 permissions
- Folder all the way up to the web root has 777 permissions
- File uploads are on
- Uploaded file is very small, within the `upload_max_filesize` range

Any ideas on why this isn't working?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Never knew that `777` is a tag o_O

Comment: Surprise! Now you do. ;)

Comment: ... Wait... IIS and *nix permission bits? What?

Comment: Sure you allowed full permission for NETWORK SERVICE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to check permissions for Network Service, right click on files OR folder name and go to security tab and see if Network Service account is added and provided full permissions.